# Outlook "sent mail" rules - only 1 firing - RESOLVED

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, email-filter, rules

I am using Outlook 2013. For various reasons I use 3 separate accounts for email, one from outlook.com and 2 from gmail.com.  However, I want the emails I compose for the outlook.com account to be available in my sent mail for both of the gmail.com accounts.

Since I do all my composing for the outlook.com account within the desktop vesion of Outlook 2013 I figured this was no problem - I connected my 2 gmail accounts via IMAP into Outlook and then set up 2 rules for sent mail. Each rule looked like this:

- Apply this rule after I send a message
- through the (outlook.com) account
- and on this computer only
- move a copy to the (sent mail folder in the appropriate IMAP store) folder

This will work for 1 rule or the other (apparently whichever one I edit/save most recently) but the other rule doesn't ever seem to fire.

I am familiar with the "stop processing more rules" action of outlook rules which would cause this type of behavior, but that is not active as far as I can tell... (Well, I see the option in the action list when I am going through the rule-making wizard but it is not checked and it doesn't show up in the summary of the rule - I suppose it could be implicit in some way?)

Do you have any ideas how I can get my sent mail from account A into the sent mail folders of accounts B and C?

(Note that solutions involving automatic BCC will work but I am avoiding them because then I don't have a record of who else was on the BCC - ideally I want to get an exact copy of these messages in all 3 "sent mail" folders.)

UPDATE: The problem has resolved itself. I have no idea what changed - I can still see the email history where emails were being copied to one account or the other from earlier, but at some point this afternoon they just all of a sudden started going to both accounts. Frustrating to not know what changed, but at least the problem is resolved.

Comment: Can you create a nonsnse rule for a test. Just make sure this new rule also has multiple 'steps' such as "after I send a message" and then mark it as unread and then move it. Just something different to see if your version of Outlook is bonkers on all rules or just this one.

Comment: Also, why have you chequed the rule `and on this computer only`

Comment: Did the checkbox turn on in Rules Wizard?